# Multiplying two matrices of different sizes by locb

Tags: r

Let's say I have two matrices, one with an rownames of size 1:n and the other of size < n and some rownames between 1 and n.

```
set.seed(123)

x <- runif(100, 0.0, 1.0)
names(x) <- 1:100
x <- as.matrix(x)

y <- runif(10,0.0,1.0)
names(y) <- c(1,16,17,30,40,57,64,90,91,110)
y <- as.matrix(y)
```

I wish to multiply x by y element wise such that for each row x with index i, it is multiplied with the the y greatest y value with index j such that i<=j. For example x(1)->y(1)*y(1), x(2)->x(2)*y(16), x(3)->x(3)*y(16). I can do this in a loop, but is there some way to take advantage of vectored operations in R if x is going to be millions of rows. I am also weary of just carrying backward (locb) y as it would make another large matrix.

Comment: What about indexes that are bigger than 92 (the biggest j)?

Comment: Ah, sorry. The biggest j will always be greater than or equal to the biggest i. I've changed that in the code from 92 to 110.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the indexes of x using `sapply`:

```
## First convert the rownames of y into numeric
yrows=as.numeric(rownames(y));
## For each row i of x, multiply x[i] by the element of y that has the smallest row index >=i
res=sapply(1:nrow(x),function(i) {x[i]*y[min(which(yrows>=i))]})
```

This returns a vector of the same length as `x`.